# SQL Query is taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Hi All below is my query written for SQL 2008. It takes more than 2 hours to insert 500000 records. Could any one suggest a way to improve performance?

```
INSERT INTO tblUserFile
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN UD.IdentityStatus = 'A' THEN 'ACTIVE'
        WHEN UD.IdentityStatus in ('T','') THEN 'INACTIVE'
        WHEN UD.IdentityStatus IS NULL THEN ''
    END,
    --'UD.IS' AS "Status",
    ISNULL(UD.HltID,'') AS "USERID",
    ISNULL(UD.HltID,'') AS "USERNAME",
    ISNULL(UD.FirstName,'') AS "FIRSTNAME",
    ISNULL(UD.LastName,'') AS "LASTNAME",
    ISNULL(UD.MiddleInitials,'') AS "MI",
    '' AS "GENDER",
    ISNULL(UD.EmailAddress,'') AS "EMAIL",
    CASE
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'C' THEN ISNULL(MCU.Manager, '') ----look into this
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'R' THEN 'From LMS SuperViser'
        WHEN SU.UserType IS NULL OR SU.UserType = ''  THEN ''
    END,
    '' AS HR,
    '' AS "DEPARTMENT",
    '' AS "JOBCODE",
    '' AS "DIVISION",
    ISNULL(UD.Office,'') AS "LOCATION",
    '' AS "TIMEZONE",
    '' AS "HIREDATE",
    ISNULL(UD.Title,'') AS "TITLE",
    ISNULL(UD.StreetAddress,'') AS "ADDR1",
    '' AS "ADDR2",
    ISNULL(UD.City,'') AS "CITY",
    ISNULL(UD.State,'') AS "STATE",
    ISNULL(UD.Zip,'') AS "ZIP",
    ISNULL(UD.CountryCode,'') AS "COUNTRY", 
    '' AS "REVIEW_FREQ",
    '' AS "LAST_REVIEW_DATE",
    ISNULL(UD.EmployeeType,'') AS "Custom01",
    '' AS "Custom02",
    CASE
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'C' THEN '' 
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'R' THEN ISNULL(FSBD.Name,'')
        WHEN SU.UserType IS NULL OR SU.UserType = ''  THEN ''
    END,
    '' AS "Custom04",
    '' AS "Custom05",
    '' AS "Custom06",
    '' AS "Custom07",
    '' AS "Custom08",
    CASE
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'C' THEN 'Corporate'
        WHEN SU.UserType = 'R' THEN 'Hotel'
        WHEN SU.UserType IS NULL OR SU.UserType = ''  THEN ''
    END,
    ISNULL(UD.EmpId,'') AS "Custom11",
    '' AS "Custom13",
    '' AS "Custom14",
    '' AS "Custom15",
    '' AS "PositionCode",
    ISNULL(SU.HomeFacility, '') AS "HomeFacility",
    'NPS' AS PSFlag
FROM Search..UserData UD
    LEFT JOIN Search..ManagerForCorpUsers MCU ------ look into this
    ON MCU.EmpID = UD.EmpId
    AND UD.EmpId != ''
    AND UD.EmpId IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN Search..securityUsers SU ------ look into this
    ON UD.UserId = SU.UserID
    AND UD.UserId != ''
    AND UD.UserId IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN EIS.dbo.NewQueryFilter NQ
    ON SU.HomeFacility = NQ.FCNB
    AND SU.HomeFacility != ''
    AND SU.HomeFacility IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN Facility..fcSubBrandDesc FSBD
    ON NQ.SubBrand = FSBD.SubBrand
    AND NQ.SubBrand != ''
    AND NQ.SubBrand IS NOT NULL
WHERE 
    ISNULL(UD.IdentityStatus,'') NOT IN ('D','U','L')
    AND ISNULL(UD.EmployeeType,'') NOT IN ('O','V','')
    AND ISNULL(UD.HltId,'')  != ''
    AND ISNULL(UD.EmpId,'') NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM Search..CurrentUserFile)
```

Comment: Are you having indexes on MCU.EmpID,  UD.EmpId, UD.UserId, SU.UserID, SU.HomeFacility, NQ.FCNB, NQ.SubBrand and FSBD.SubBrand. Also on  UD.IdentityStatus, UD.EmployeeType and UD.HltId ?

Comment: How long does the SELECT take without the insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried avoiding inner query for `DISTINCT` query?

what is the size of Search..CurrentUserFile??

try something like this -

```
SELECT
....
FROM Search..UserData UD
    ...  -- all your earlier joins as it is
    LEFt JOIN Search..CurrentUserFile CU on (UD.EmpId=CU.UserId)
WHERE
    ... -- all your where clause
    AND CU.UserId IS NULL;--only show results which are not in CurrentUserFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Search.dbo.UserData UD
    WHERE ISNULL(UD.UserId, '') != ''
        AND ISNULL(UD.IdentityStatus, '') NOT IN ('D','U','L')
        AND ISNULL(UD.EmployeeType, '') NOT IN ('O','V','')
        AND ISNULL(UD.HltId, '') != ''
        AND ISNULL(UD.EmpId, '') NOT IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT UserId 
                        FROM Search.dbo.CurrentUserFile
                    )
) UD
LEFT JOIN Search.dbo.ManagerForCorpUsers MCU ON MCU.EmpID = UD.EmpId
LEFT JOIN Search.dbo.securityUsers SU ON UD.UserId = SU.UserID
LEFT JOIN EIS.dbo.NewQueryFilter NQ ON SU.HomeFacility = NQ.FCNB 
    AND ISNULL(SU.HomeFacility, '') != ''
LEFT JOIN Facility.dbo.fcSubBrandDesc FSBD ON NQ.SubBrand = FSBD.SubBrand 
    AND ISNULL(NQ.SubBrand, '') != ''
```

Comment: And also don't use ""/'' ([COLUMN] AS 'COLUMN NAME'), more preferable use square brackets for column name - [COLUMN] AS [COLUMN NAME]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Recovery model as Transaction it would log all, "You could use BUlk Logged Recovery If you have more inserts taking place , and Try minimizing the Case Statements use Joins Instead and LEft Joins Instead Not in Conditions